# remove gap between div tags

Tags: css, html

There is an unnecessary gap between two divs..Is there any solution to remove that?
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/)
If you observe the `vUiTsTabs` and `vUiTsContainers` div tags, you will find a gap between those two divs...(gap between black and red border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the display and clear the `float:left` on the lis by setting

```
display:inline-block;
overflow:hidden; /*or auto*/
```

for `.vUiTsTabs` and the gap will disappear: [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/2)

Comment: this is not enough, it does not display properly in Chrome if you do not clear the <ul> tag http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/18/

Comment: @Luca I did this, but forgot to mention in the answer. Thanks for the catch;)

Comment: Thanks for your response.It works fine..I have another small problem..I want to set the selected tab as part of the container.For that I m thinking to put it some what down that overlaps container border upto tab space.But I m not able to achieve this..can you help me... here is the new fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/35/..Take a look at this...http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/index.html

Comment: @RamaRaoM You should address this in another question. Basically you need to use positioning and `top:1px` on the selected tab to overlay the border of the content-div.

Answer (score 2):

clear the `<ul>` tag (`overflow: auto;` is enough)
and remove `display: inline-block;` from `.vUiTsTabs`

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/3/

Answer (score 1):

Replace `float: left` for the li with `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may be helpful to you 
use this `.vUiTsTabs` code

```
.vUiTsTabs {
border-bottom: 1px solid #660033;
display: table;
margin: 0;
width: 99.9%;
}
```

Demo: [modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/11/)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it on Chrome putting 'vertical-align: top' in your vUiTsTabs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Use following css:

```
.vUiTsTabs {
   display: table;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #660033;
   width: 99.9%;
}
```

Comment: "grey blocks" are used to highlight code only, not your comment mixed with code :)

Comment: seriously dude learn how to use the correct code highlight syntax

Comment: @Luca I understand. hereafter this will not happen again.

Comment: let me reiterate it - you should not use bold style for code. you should use `this format`, the way I've edited your post a few times, and you've again reverted it. kindly refrain from doing it so